# Multiple Libstreaming streams First Stream Freeze after second stream request

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp, libstreaming

I am using [Libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) for stream Camera Video.
Single stream instance working good. But i want to stream at least 2 instance of the same camera feed.

I got some hint from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058706/multiple-libstreaming-streams-only-recognized-as-session-of-first-rtsp-client) that setting variable port to "video.setDestinationPorts(5006);" instead of fix 5006 might help. If i make this variable. I got camera open error on second request.

So i saved the mVideoStream from the first session and retrieved on second session request. Now i not getting camera open error and successfully start the new stream. But Now the issue is the First stream got freeze.

So what's the issue?